# How get I interpret the value of RMSE in randomForest between h2o.performance and validation matric?

Tags: r, h2o

I've used `h2o package` to run random forest. To figure out that my model is bad or good, I looked for `RMSE`.(Models are sorted by `RMSE`)

```
h2o.final1618.rf <- h2o.getModel(rf.sortedGrid.1618.2@model_ids[[1]])

h2o.final1618.rf@model$validation_metrics@metrics

h2o.final1618.rf@model$training_metrics@metrics
```

I could get the values of RMSE through validation metrics and training metrics. 
The value of `RMSE` of `validation_metrics` is `0.4526.`
The value of `RMSE` of `training_metrics` is `0.4571.`

But, I used `h2o.performance` function or `h2o.predict` function to get the values of `RMSE`, the values by `h2o.performance` is `0.2852` and it's smaller than the values of validation and train metrics above.

```
perf <- h2o.performance(h2o.final1618.rf, newdata = h2o.incheon1618[[2]])
```

`h2o.incheon1618[[2]]` is validation data.(I split data set 0.7 and 0.2 and 0.1 ; train data, validation data, test data)

I couldn't understand why the difference is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use these parameters for 'performance' `valid=TRUE, xval=FALSE` and ignore the newdata parameter you will get what you are after.